# Pipe continuous stream to multiple files

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a program which will be running continuously writing output to stdout, and I would like to continuously take the last set of output from it and write this to a file.  Each time a new set of output comes along, I'd like to overwrite the same file.

An example would be the following command:

```
iostat -xkd 5
```

Every 5 seconds this prints some output, with a blank line after each one.  I'd like the last "set" to be written to a file, and I think this should be achievable with something simple.

So far I've tried using xargs, which I could only get to do this with a single line, rather than a group of lines delimited by something.

I think it might be possible with awk, but I can't figure out how to get it to either buffer the data as it goes along so it can write it out using system, or get it to close and reopen the same output file.

**EDIT**: To clarify, this is a single command which will run continuously.  I do NOT want to start a new command and read the output of that.

**SOLUTION**

I adapted the answer from @Bittrance to get the following:

```
iostat -xkd 5 | (while read r; do
        if [ -z "$r" ]; then
                mv -f /tmp/foo.out.tmp /tmp/foo.out
        else
                echo "$r" >> /tmp/foo.out.tmp
        fi
done)
```

This was basically the same, apart from detecting the end of a "section" and writing to a temp file so that whenever an external process tried to read the output file it would be complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer:

```
./your_command | (while read r ; do 
    if ... ; then
        rm -f foo.out
    fi
    echo $r >> foo.out
done)
```

If there is a condition (the ...) such that you know that you are receiving the first line of the "set" this would work.

Comment: Interesting option, I hadn't thought of doing it like that. I managed to adapt your partial solution to get something that works - I'll post what I used in the question

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
while :; do
  iostat -xkd > FILE
  sleep 5
done
```

If you're set on using `awk` the following writes each output from `iostat` to a numbered file:

```
iostat -xkd 5 | awk -v RS=$'\n'$'\n' '{ print >NR; close(NR) }'
```

Note: the first record is the header that `iostat` outputs.

Comment: This is not the same thing - it runs the program again each loop.  The program needs to stay running.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** In reply to comment, I tested this perl solution to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

$|=1;

open(STDOUT, '>', '/tmp/iostat.running') or die $!;

while(<>)
{
    seek (STDOUT, 0, 0) if (m/^$/gio);
    print
}
```

So now you can

```
iostat -xkd 5 | myscript.pl&
```

And watch the snapshots:

```
watch -n10 cat /tmp/iostat.running
```

If you wanted to make sure that enough space is overwritten at the end (since the output length might vary slightly each time), you could print some padding at the end, like e.g.:

```
    print "***"x40 and seek (STDOUT, 0, 0) if (m/^$/gio);
```

(snipped old answer text since apparently it was confusing people)

Comment: Repeatedly running iostat with a sleep 5 inbetween is not the same as running it continuously.  I cannot afford the logfile to grow unbounded - it will essentially be running forever.

Comment: A fifo is possibly an interesting option, but not sure how I could get it to work, and the length of the output may vary slightly.

Comment: Hah. I got it licked now, if you care to use perl. See edited answer.

Comment: That seems to do what I intended.  I'd just finished adapting bittrance's answer when you posted this though.  Cheers!

Comment: Addressed the problem of varying length by padding as well now, to make the idea more robust/complete

Comment: Just one comment - I know I didn't specify anything about having a partial file for if the read process arrived while the output was being written, but it's something I realised was necessary after you pointed it out!  However, it would be easy enough to modify the program so that rather than seeking to 0, it closed the file, moved it to another file and started again.

Comment: Yup, that would be straightforward, I think